# Problem in Understanding an Example to a Corollary of the Replacement Theorem in Vector Spaces from the book "Linear Algebra" by Stephen H Friedberg

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

I was studying Bases and Dimensions for Vector Spaces in Linear Algebra from the book titled, "Linear Algebra" by S Freedberg, A Insel and L Spence.

From what I understood, was that:

> - A subset $S$ of a vector space $V$ is called a basis for $V$ iff $\text{span}(S)=V$ and $S$ is linearly independent.
> - If a vector space $V$ has a finite basis then $V$ has a finite dimension and is equal to the number of elements in the basis. It is often denoted by $\dim (V).$ A vector space is called to be of infinite dimension if it is not finite dimension.

In Chapter-1 (Vector Spaces) on Section- 1.6 titled as "Bases and Dimensions" at Page number-47 (in the 4th Edition of the book) there was a Corollary (titled as $Corollary-2$) to the Replacement Theorem, which was, as follows:

> **Corollary 2.** Let $V$ be a vector space with dimension $n.$
>
> (a) Any finite generating set for $V$ contains at least $n$ vectors, and a generating set for $V$ that contains exactly $n$ vectors is a basis for $V.$
>
> (b) Any linearly independent subset of $V$ that contains exactly n vectors is a basis for $V.$
>
> (c) Every linearly independent subset of $V$ can be extended to a basis for $V.$

---

After that, there were some examples given. My problem is with understanding an example. I will first present the example below:

> We have, $P_2(F)$ as the vector space of all the polynomials of degree $2$ over the field $F.$ We note that, the set $S=\{x^2 + 3x − 2, 2x^2 + 5x − 3, −x^2 − 4x + 4\}$ generates $P_2(F).$ Now, it follows from (a) of Corollary-2 that, $S$ is a basis for $P_2(F).$

---

In here, I dont get how are they saying, " **it follows from (a) of Corollary-2** that, $S$ is a basis for $P_2(F)$."

My point is, that I understand that why $S$ is basis for $P_2(F).$ This is because

- $\text{span}(S)=P_2(F)$ and
- if, $\exists a,b,c\in F$ such that $a(x^2 + 3x − 2)+ b(2x^2 + 5x − 3)+c(−x^2 − 4x + 4)=0$ then, we have, $a=b=c=0$ and this implies that $S$ is linearly independent.

But **I don't understand how Corollary 2(a)** helps us to assert, that $S$ is a basis for $P_2(F).$ This is because, we can use **Corollary-2** only when we know the dimension of $P_2(F).$ And, we can be aware of the dimension of $P_2(F)$ only if, we know the cardinality of a finite basis of $P_2(F).$ However, in this case, before applying $Corollary-2$ we don't have any idea what is the cardinality of a finite basis of $P_2(F)$ might be and hence, we never know the dimensions of $P_2(F)$ whether it's finite or infinite and if finite what's the precise valie of dimension. ***Hence, we cannot apply Corollary $2$ on $S$ just after noting that $\text{span}(S)=P_2(F)$***. We also have to find  the dimension, of $P_2(F)$ to apply it.

Did I miss anything? I am very much confused. Any help regarding this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The set $\{ 1,x,x^2 \}$ is a basis of this space and hence, the dimension is $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Shankar has mentioned in comments above, $\mathsf{P}_2(F)$ has dimension $3$.

And Friedberg’s book actually has mentioned this, in page 43, **Example 4**, that the **standard basis** for $\mathsf{P}_n(F)$ is defined to be $\{ 1, x, x^2, \ldots, x^n \}$. And in page 47, **Example 10** says $\mathsf{P}_n(F)$ has dimension $n + 1$.